# How to create different contents using Pager in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android-viewpager, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewpager2

I want to develop an onboarding flow having different contents using Pager in Jetpack Compose.
Because I want for a user to put her different values.

Ex)

- page1: She will input her name using a textfield.
- page2: She will input her sex using a dropdown menu.
- page3: She will read my app's service term.

I mean there screens have different contents.

When I read [the doc](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/pager), we can see the content inside have alike contents like below.

```
val pagerState = rememberPagerState()

HorizontalPager(pageCount = 10, state = pagerState) { page ->
    // page content
    Text(
        text = "Page: $page",
    )
}
```

How can I set different contents using pager?

Should I use `when` block and a `pagerState.scrollToPage` method?

Please teach me how to write the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in the documentation and in the code, you're getting `page` number through lambda.

You'll have to add `if` or `when` statement and show the content based on page number. It'll be something like this :

```
val pagerState = rememberPagerState()

HorizontalPager(pageCount = 10, state = pagerState) { page ->

    when(page){
       
        0 -> {
            InputName()
        }

        1 -> {
            GenderSelection()
        }

        2 -> {
            TermsOfService()
        }

    }

}
```

Here `InputName()`, `GenderSelection()`, `TermsOfService()` are all different `@Composable` functions/screens.